# Generate a Vector File of Pixel Art with Hard Pixelated Edges

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, file-format

I am working on a project where I am engraving some pixel artwork onto an acrylic sheet using laser cutting. This process requires a vector file for the laser, but whenever I try to vectorize my artwork all the hard pixel edges (which are intentional artistic choices in this case, the image is meant to look pixelated), get converted into goofy looking curves.

Is there any method I can use to do a 1 to 1 transfer and trace my pixels exactly as a vector with no smoothing? Been looking in Illustrator and a few online png to vector converters but haven't found anything that does this.

Thanks!

This question is not the same as : "How to convert every pixel of raster picture to square objects in Illustrator?"

I actively do not want a bunch of individual squares. I would like the whole contiguous colored area traced, creating a single object, but preserving the pixelated edges. This is a different question then the one you have marked as the same.

Comment: use the mosaic function on the image

Answer (score 0):

No auto-tracing feature or tool is 100% accurate. None of them. It doesn't matter what settings you adjust or even what tool you use. They are never meant to be a 1:1 conversion.

They *all* initiate some anti-aliasing and blurring to detect edges, then perform "best guess" operations as to where edges fall. Auto-tracing is never *precise*, at best it can be "pretty close".

If you want solid, stair step, edges I'm afraid you'll need to do that *manually*. Tracing always assumes "stair stepping" is due to the pixel nature of raster image originals and *never* an intentional appearance.

All that being posted.. the larger the original raster image is, the higher the probability of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is relatively small in pixel size and has a limited number of colors, a way to do it is actually making a grid, and starting filling colors square by square. This way you will get perfect pixel art in vector format.

Then you should join the adjacent same color squares into one shape.

---

If you want auto trace, **try to resample it several orders in magnitude**, let's say your image is 64x64px try 50x with **"nearest neighbor"**. Your image will be now 3200x3200px and still will be pixel art, but the software will be forced to consider all the information to generate more accurate lines, than just scaling your 64x64px image.